# Is it possible to calculate the height and distance of an object if the horizon is obstructed?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, recreational-mathematics

Basically, if I know $x$, $\theta_1$, and $\theta_2$ in the image below, it is possible to determine $h_1$ and $d$, or do I also need to know $h_2$ first?

[image: Vertical lines are connected to a horizontal line. Then lines extend from the top of the objects to two points on the horizontal line. The angle between the new lines and the closer point is theta 1, while the angle between the new lines and the farther point is theta 2. The distance between the horizontal points is labeled x and the distance from the near point to the longer vertical line is labeled d. Then the heights of the vertical lines are labeled h 1 and h 2]

If the horizon is visible, then the calculation is easy:

[image: Similar image as before, but there is only one vertical line and the angles are measured from the horizontal line.]

We can write $\tan \theta_1 = \frac{h}{d}$ and $\tan \theta_2 = \frac{h}{d+x}$ from which we can conclude $d = \frac{x}{\frac{\tan \theta_1}{\tan \theta_2}-1}$ and $h = \frac{x\cdot \tan \theta_1 \tan \theta_2}{\tan \theta_1 - \tan \theta_2}$. But I'm stumped by the top case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the "obstructed" case, we can construct an alternative figure with values of
$\theta_1$, $\theta_2$, and $x$ the same as in your first figure, but different values of $h_1$ and $h_2.$ (Just move the "obstruction" point up and to the left so that the two sides of angle $\theta_1$ are unchanged, but the lower side of angle $\theta_2$ is rotated upward; then the upper side of angle $\theta_2$ also is rotated upward, resulting in an intersection point that is higher.)

So you cannot determine $h_1$ from just $\theta_1$, $\theta_2$, and $x$.

But if you have a line of sight between the two viewpoints, don't measure the angles subtended by the tops of the segments $h_1$ and $h_2,$ measure the angle subtended by the top of $h_1$ and the other viewpoint.
Then you have one side and two adjacent angles of a triangle and you can determine all three sides of the triangle, and you can then use trigonometry to compute $h_1$ from the known angles and distances.